# Передача данных между классами

Tags: c#, классы

Вопрос состоит в следующем.
Есть 2 класса `foo` и `Form1` (`foo` создается в процессе работы `Form1`).
На форме `Form1` есть `RichTextBox`, в котором выводиться лог событий.
При возникновении Иксэзшена (`Exception e`) в классе `foo` необходимо каким то способом передать `e.Message` в `RichTextBox`. Как реализовать данную возможность?

Comment: а в чем проблема-то? Про try-catch что-нибудь слышали?

Comment: Слышал. Вопрос не в том как отловить эксэпшн. а как передать инфу из класса foo в класс Form1 что бы вывести это дело в RichTextBox.

Comment: как-то расплывчато у вас описана проблема. Но так или иначе, вопрос передачи данных из одного класса в другой - задача не из сложных

Comment: `form1.richTextBox.Text += e.Message;`

Comment: @fori1ton form1.richTextBox не доступен из foo без создания экземпляра класса. А при создании экземпляра вывод будет осуществлен не на то, что непосредственно видит юзер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передаём в конструктор `foo` экземпляр класса `Form1` и сохраняем его в private-поле класса `foo`. Теперь мы можем обращаться к RichTextBox именно того экземпляра `Form1`, в котором был создан экземпляр `foo`.

```
public class foo {
    private Form1 form;

    public foo(Form1 form) {
        this.form = form;
    }

    public someMethod() {
        try {
            // что-то делаем
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.form.RichTextBox.Text += e.Message;
        }
    }

}
```

В классе `Form1`:

```
foo f = new foo(this);
f.someMethod();
```

Comment: а если foo надо будет перенести в wpf, то придется переделывать foo. лучше `try catch` вынести в `form1`, туда где вызывается `someMethod` и там же выводить `e.Message` в `richtextbox`.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ выше не верен.
Сделайте обертку исключения над методом класса foo, который вызывается в классе Form1.
Передавать клиентскую логику вниз по иерархии классов - плохо.

Comment: Если уж говорить об архитектуре, операции, производящие исключения, явно принадлежат бизнес-логике, и должны быть выгружены в соответствующий layer. Кроме того, показывать текст исключения пользователю нельзя, это — чисто отладочная информация, нелокализованная, и потенциально нарушающая конфиденциальность данных.